# HTML. CSS. Textarea выходит за пределы родительского DIV

Tags: html, css, textarea

Textarea имеет в CSS ширину 100%, однако выходит за пределы родительского DIV.
   Если обнулить padding и border, тот всё нормально, но border мне нужен!

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Есть ещё вариант, указать явно максимальную ширину в пикселях:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 496px; // вместо 500px = 100% 
    resize: none;
}
```

Такой вариант тоже не катит, так как по разному поведёт себя на разных экранах.
   Тема вроде обсуждаемая, но толкового ответа не нашёл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `box-sizing: border-box;`:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: лучше даже задать его для всех элементов. `*{box-sizing:border-box}` . `border-box`  как-то интуитивно понятнее, чем `content-box`

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров, согласен, но в этом случае, если вёрстка уже сделана с учетом особенностей `content-box`, она может поползти.

Comment: Впервые слышу о box-sizing (border-box и content-box), но уже по названию понятно о чём тут речь. -moz-box-sizing, очевидно, применяет этот подход в Mozzila Firefox, а вот для каких браузеров применяется  -webkit-box-sizing?

Comment: Для браузеров на движке webkit (Chrome, Opera, Яндекс.Браузер и т.д.)